# Let $f : \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a func such that $p>0$, that $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ . Show that $f$ has an absolute max and min

Tags: real-analysis

***Problem:*** Let $f : \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a contiunous function such that for some real number $p>0$, $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Show that $f$ has an absolute max and min.

***Thoughts:***
By rolle's theorem, I know that between $f(x+p)$ and $f(x)$ there has to be a local minimum if $f$ is differentiable on this open interval, but I am outright confused by the precise statement of the question, and in fact I have included an image which may be a counter-example if the question has not been stated properly(sorry for the crudeness of the image) assuming the function continues in this manner infinitely [image]

Edit: As per a comment, since $f$ is not shown to be differentiable on this interval, then Rolle's theorem does not apply.

Also see my answer for a response to my initial confusion.

Comment: Your example is not really a counter-example, since the function is not being periodic. For instance, $f(0) = f(0+q)$ only holds for finitely many $q$, and it should hold for $q=p, 2p, 3p,\ldots$

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @carmichael561 yes sorry edited.

Comment: Rolle's theorem doesn't apply.  No one said it is differentiable.  Also, $f'(x)=0$ does not imply that $f$ has a min or max at $x$, even if $f$ were differentiable.  Even if it happened to give local min/max, no guarantee of global.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Your first, and foremost observation in this question, is that since the function is basically repeating itself after a distance of $p$, it is enough to consider the behaviour of $f$ on a finite interval. Can you see this? I should add : this statement is absolutely true, there aren't any counterexamples to this one.

Comment: @JonasMeyer good point, edited to reflect that.

Comment: I have added an answer that corresponds to my initial confusion for anyone in the future experiencing that same confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that if a real-valued function $g(x)$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, then it has a global maximum and minimum on $[a,b]$.

And since $f(x)$ is periodic with period $p$, it follows that $f$ is determined by its values on $[0,p]$. Therefore the global maximum for $f$ on $[0,p]$ is a global maximum for $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You're on the right track using Rolle's theorem since usually, whenever the derivative is zero a (local) maximum or minimum is expected. However, this is not guaranteed, and moreover, as @Jonas pointed out, this requires the function to be differentiable, which we don't know in advance. Instead, use the following theorem

> A continuous function defined on a closed interval always reaches its maximum and minimum value.

I leave you a hint for the next step below, but I encourage you to try it on your own before taking a look at it :)

> The idea is to apply this theorem on the interval $[0,p]$, then you get local min and max. Can you show these are actually global?

Comment: Even if $f$ were differentiable, Rolle's theorem would give zeros of the derivative, not global max or mins.  I don't see how it would help.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Right, I left myself go with OP's thoughts. I fixed the answer.

Comment: I edited my comment based on your edited answer, still not seeing how Rolle's theorem would be "the right track".

Comment: @JonasMeyer Forgot about that, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem: Any continuous map on a closed interval has a max and a min.**

Apply this to the interval $[0,p]$. Since for any $x \in R$ we have some $x_0 \in [0,p]$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)$, the maximum on that sub-interval is in fact a global max.

Note: No differentiability assumption was made.